# Creating a Responsive Layout with Flexbox: Expanding Content Boxes for Mobile View

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I create a responsive layout with expanding content boxes using flexbox for mobile devices? I have designed a layout with expanding flexboxes, but I want it to display properly on mobile devices. How can I ensure that the boxes break and stack correctly for mobile view?

For More details I have 3 column and on column:hover it is 0 0 550px; I want to expand the div to bottom on mobile device.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}
body {
    background-color: #10172b;
    font-family: Poppins, Arial, "sans-serif";
    color: #ffffff;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: #10172b;
    width: 100vw;
}
.widget-image {
    padding-top: 10vh;
    display: inline-block;
}
.column {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    transition: flex 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #293346;
    margin-right: 20px;
    flex-direction:row;
}
.column:hover {
    flex: 0 0 30%;
    transition: 0.5s;
 
}
.column:hover .widget-image {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.column:hover .learn-more-button {
    margin: 0px;
}
.responsive {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.learn-more-button {
    background-color: #6d38f1;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding: 10px 24px;
    border: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px;
    text-align: left;
}
.learn-more-button:hover {
    background-color: #15E333;
    transition: flex 2.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
.column:hover>button.hide {
    display: inline-block;
    transition: 2s;
}
.column:hover>p.hide {
    display: inline-block;
}
.description {
    
    text-align: justify;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.column:hover .description {
    display: block;
    transition: 1.5s;
}
.heading-prix {
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    font-family: Poppins, "sans-serif";
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <p class="heading-prix">Title</p>
    <p class="description hide">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</p>
    <img src="https://placehold.co/350x300.png" alt="Services" class="widget-image responsive"  />
    <button class="learn-more-button hide" style="align-items: flex-end;"  >Learn More &nbsp;&nbsp; &#9658;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p class="heading-prix">Title</p>
    <p class="description hide">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</p>
    <img src="https://placehold.co/350x300.png" alt="Warehouse" class="widget-image responsive" />
    <button class="learn-more-button hide">Learn More &nbsp;&nbsp; &#9658;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p class="heading-prix">Title</p>
    <p class="description hide">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</p>
    <img src="https://placehold.co/350x300.png" alt="IIOT" class="widget-image responsive" />
    <button class="learn-more-button hide">Learn More &nbsp;&nbsp; &#9658;</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When using *absolute length unit* (px) size values (width/height/padding/margin/font) you are a long way off getting a responsive layout. You might want to investigate [MDN: CSS values and units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units), [MDN: length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) to understand their relevance to [MDN: Responsive design](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design).

Comment: I have updated the code I want the box should breakdown to stack.

Comment: What do you mean with 'mobile view'? Portrait versus Landscape? Viewport size? Your question is way to broad for a simple answer. In HTML/CSS there is no such thing as a single 'mobile view'. Some have a 360x720 screen, others a 1440x2560, while their browser often show different viewport sizes. Here's a list with examples: [Viewport by Device](https://www.icwebdesign.co.uk/common-viewport-sizes). That's where 'breakpoints'  and 'media queries' come in.